# footnotes in pre defined commands only once in the result

Tags: footnotes, acronyms

I have the situation, that several people generate together a document and pre defined phrases (commands) are often in use. And footnotes will be duplicate with this kind of work flow. The following MWE illustrates it:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\texsx}{There is a popular website about \TeX{}: \TeX{} \textsc{StackExchange}\footnote{\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{A}
\texsx{}
\section{B}
\texsx{}
\chapter{Second}
\texsx{}
\end{document}
```

Using `fixfoot` reduce the number of footnotes a little bit, but they are printed on every page, which is not the wished result:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fixfoot}
\urldef\texsxurl\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\DeclareFixedFootnote{\texsxfootnote}{\texsxurl}
\newcommand{\texsx}{There is a popular website about \TeX{}: \TeX{} \textsc{StackExchange}\texsxfootnote{}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{A}
\texsx{}
\section{B}
\texsx{}
\chapter{Second}
\texsx{}
\end{document}
```

As a smarter solution I tried to use (or misuse) the `acronym` package for it.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[footnote,nolist]{acronym}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{texsx}[\TeX{} \textsc{StackExchange}]{\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}}
\end{acronym}
\newcommand{\texsx}{There is a popular website about \TeX{}: \ac{texsx}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{A}
\texsx{}
\section{B}
\texsx{}
\chapter{Second}
\texsx{}
\end{document}
```

It is working, however, a regular list of acronyms can not be generated. Is there a better solution for commands with footnotes which should be printed once, or only once per chapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can emulate the acronym making packages. Here is how you can show the footnote only at first appearance of the phrase.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand{\definephrase}[3]{%
 % #1 = control sequence
 % #2 = text
 % #3 = footnote for first appearance
 \gdef#1{#2\footnote{#3}\gdef#1{#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\definephraseurl}[2]{%
  % #1 = control sequence
  % #2 = text
  % #3 = url (it's an apparent argument, processed
  %      by \urldef)
  \gdef#1{#2\footnote{\csname url\string#1\endcsname}%
          \gdef#1{#2}}%
  \expandafter\urldef\csname url\string#1\endcsname\url}

\definephrase{\texsx}
  {There is a popular website about \TeX{}: \TeX{} \textsc{StackExchange}}
  {\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}}

\definephraseurl{\foo}
  {A foo site}
  {http://foo.foo.foo/%7Efoo}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{A}
\texsx{}

\foo{}

\section{B}
\texsx{}

\foo{}

\chapter{Second}
\texsx{}

\foo{}
\end{document}
```

The `\definephraseurl` can be used when the URL has special characters.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the following solution can accomplish your needs.

1. Remove the `nolist` option when loading the `acronym` package otherwise the "List of acronyms" won't be printed.
2. Put the `acronym` environment after `\begin{document}` or you'll get errors.

In the following MWE I added the `colorlinks` option when loading `hyperref` because I like it this way, but you can change it.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}
\newcommand{\texsx}{There is a popular website about \TeX{}: \ac{texsx}}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{List of Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{texsx}[\TeX{} \textsc{StackExchange}]{\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}}
\end{acronym}
\chapter{First}
\section{A}
\texsx{}
\section{B}
\texsx{}
\chapter{Second}
\texsx{}
\end{document}
```

> [image]